# Postgres could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory?

Tags: sql, linux, database, postgresql, manjaro

I am using 4.14.10-2-MANJARO.
I have tried to install Postgres Database.
I have installed postgresql 10.1-1 by using command:

```
yaourt -S postgresql
```

And then:

```
sudo -u postgres -i

initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'

createuser --interactive
```

And then I have got something like this:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't know how to solve it.
I have been using this website:

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Installing_PostgreSQL
```

Then I would like to create a new database by command:

```
createdb myDatabaseName
```

Thank you.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is the server running locally and 2) accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: @wildplasser Actually there is single question: "did you try to google for `connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"`"?

Comment: @wildplasser ad 1) I don;t know but I think that no and I don't know how to run it. Abelisto Yes I tried but there is so many description how to make it and none of them work. Maybe it is because I am using Manjaro and it is based on Arch and most of answers are regarding to Ubuntu.

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl status postgresql.service`? From the error message it sounds as if the server is not running. Did `initdb` produce any error output?

Comment: Ok. Personally I never facing with such problem but as I read it is because there is no DB cluster. Try https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html and good luck.

Comment: of course you ran `pg_ctl -D '/var/lib/postgres/data' start`?..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I am also running `4.19.1-1-MANJARO` and `postgresql 10.5-3`, but most answers are for Ubuntu and refers to directories that don't exist on Manjaro.

You have to run systemctl to check the service to see what is wrong

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

It gives something like this

```
systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
postgres[3902]: "/var/lib/postgres/data" is missing >
postgres[3902]:   su - postgres -c "initdb --locale >
```

and it tells you to run the `su` command listed above. But this requires the password of the user `postgres`. To go around this we `sudo` the command instead.

```
sudo su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D /var/lib/postgres/data'"
```

When this command is finished it tells you to run `pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data start`, but instead just start it via systemctl.

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the data directory with `initdb`, you need to start the database server process with

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data start
```

But before that, you should edit `/var/lib/postgres/data.postgresql.conf` and set parameters like `listen_addresses`, `port`, `shared_buffers` and everything concerning logging.

That way, you can consult the log file after starting the server to see if everything went well.